# Zend jquery form autocomplete popoulate data in 2 fields

Tags: zend-framework, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, zendx

I have Zend autocomplete field, there I can add City name, my question is how to populate data from the list in 2 field, in 1 value and in 2 (hidden) id;

```
$this->view->autocompleteElement = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete('cmp_name');
            $this->view->autocompleteElement->setJQueryParam('source','/client/search');
```

I think this is possible because I pass array

```
[{"id":"2","value":"2","label":"Vardenisas!!!!!"},{"id":"23","value":"23","label":"Vardas"},{"id":"32","value":"32","label":"aaaaaaa"}]
```

If someone know how to in one click pass in 1 filed `label` and in 2 (hidden) `id` ?